# Creating Pandas Dataframe from Unequal Arrays Parsed using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to produce a dataframe of two columns. The first column is to contain the name of football leagues. The second column is to contain the names of teams in those leagues.

I can scrape and parse the data but because there are multiple team names for each league names I keep getting `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`.

Here's my code:

```
league_names = soup.find_all(class_='panel-title')
team_names = soup.find_all('a', class_="odds")

a = [data.text.strip() for data in league_names]
b = [data.text.strip() for data in team_names]

df = pd.DataFrame({'league_names':a, 'team_names':b}, columns=['league_names','team_names'])
```

Here's the desired output:

| league_names | team_names |
| --- | --- |
| Albania Championship | Dinamo Tirana - Skenderbeu Korce |
| Albania Championship | KF Teuta - FK Egnatia |
| Albania Championship | Vllaznia Shkoder - FK Kukesi |

Here's a screenshot of the html (code itself is below but I can't seem to paste it correctly even following [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110126/how-can-i-paste-html-markup-into-a-stack-overflow-question-field) instructions).

[image]

html:

```
<div class="panel">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                <a class="" title="Click to expand Albania Championship" data-toggle="collapse" href="#_l10041047" aria-expanded="true">
                                                    Albania Championship                                                </a>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="_l10041047" class="panel-collapse collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">

                                            <ul class="nav list-group">
                                                                                                    <li>
                                                        <a class="odds" onclick="loadEventData('119024520',this)" title="Dinamo Tirana - Skenderbeu Korce">Dinamo Tirana - Skenderbeu Korce</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                                                                    <li>
                                                        <a class="odds" onclick="loadEventData('119024522',this)" title="KF Teuta - FK Egnatia">KF Teuta - FK Egnatia</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                                                                    <li>
                                                        <a class="odds" onclick="loadEventData('119024524',this)" title="Vllaznia Shkoder - FK Kukesi">Vllaznia Shkoder - FK Kukesi</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                
                                            </ul>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid multiple lists with maybe different length, try to change your scraping strategy. Based on your examples select all `<a>` with class `odds` from the panels and combine them with its previous `<h4>`:

```
data = []
for l in soup.select('div.panel a.odds'):
    data.append({
        'league':l.find_previous('h4').text.strip(),
        'teams':l.text
    })
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

html = '''
<div class="panel">
<div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="" title="Click to expand Albania Championship" data-toggle="collapse" href="#_l10041047" aria-expanded="true">
                Albania Championship                                                </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="_l10041047" class="panel-collapse collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">

        <ul class="nav list-group">
                                                                <li>
                    <a class="odds" onclick="loadEventData('119024520',this)" title="Dinamo Tirana - Skenderbeu Korce">Dinamo Tirana - Skenderbeu Korce</a>
                </li>
                                                                <li>
                    <a class="odds" onclick="loadEventData('119024522',this)" title="KF Teuta - FK Egnatia">KF Teuta - FK Egnatia</a>
                </li>
                                                                <li>
                    <a class="odds" onclick="loadEventData('119024524',this)" title="Vllaznia Shkoder - FK Kukesi">Vllaznia Shkoder - FK Kukesi</a>
                </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
data = []
for l in soup.select('div.panel a.odds'):
    data.append({
        'league':l.find_previous('h4').text.strip(),
        'teams':l.text
    })
    
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

###### Output

| league | teams |
| --- | --- |
| Albania Championship | Dinamo Tirana - Skenderbeu Korce |
| Albania Championship | KF Teuta - FK Egnatia |
| Albania Championship | Vllaznia Shkoder - FK Kukesi |